# How to make a static Helper that work differently on client and server side?

Tags: c#, abstract

I have a Helper that define some static method.

At the moment i duplicate the Helper in both Client and Server Project.

The helper look like this.

```
public static partial class WeekEndTripHelper
{
   private static bool FindOutIfItsADayOff(DateTime time)
   {
        //SOME CODE
        var holidays = GetPublicHolidays();
   }       

   public static List<PublicHoliday> GetPublicHolidays()
   {
   }
}
```

The only difference between client side and service side... 
Is the implementation of GetPublicHolidays.

In client i called a list of holiday that io get earlier and store in memory

And in service i called the bdd to get them.
(Yes my holiday are in bdd don't ask why ^^)

So i would like to make this GetPublicHolidays abstract and then do a new class in client and service that are child of my Helper class and implement GetPublicHolidays

But visual say i can't make a static method abstract. So how can i do that?

Comment: Are you using an IoC container in your application?

Comment: To be honnest i don't even know what a IoC container is im checking google atm

Comment: how about DI the instance class and call this static class from inside thats instance class.....?

Comment: normally Inject static is not achievable, because we are not maintain static

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the class `WeekEndTripHelper` neither `partial` nor `static` but declaring it as `abstract` in order to use it as a base class. The method `FindOutIfItsADayOff()` doesnt have to be `abstract` though. Rather set `GetPublicHolidays()` `abstract`. Then let the client side and server side inherit from `WeekEndTripHelper` and implement the `GetPublicHolidays()` method on both sides different, so the way you want it to be.

Answer (score -3):

For example, you can create an abstract base class with an abstract GetPublicHolidays() method. Than you can create 2 subclass (client, server) and implement the different GetPublicHolidays() methods in each subclass. Last step, if you want to use that classes as static, you can use singleton pattern, or you can use an IoC container.

Comment: I don't understand the vote down on this answer. Because its actually a possible solution to my problem.
I am looking about IoC container at the moment to see if it fits.

Comment: Me neither :) The following two solution suggestions are the same as I wrote (without down vote).

Comment: Maybe its about the way of writting... sample/espace ect... btw i try different solution before giving up vote and choose answer